# An identity with vector products

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, invariant-theory

Consider $a$, $b$, $c$, $a'$, $b'$, $c'$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Denote by $[ab]$ the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the vectors $a$, $b$, $(a b)$ their [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), and $[abc] = ([ab]c)$ their mixed product. Let $x=[bc]$, $x'=[b'c']$, $y =[ca]$, $y'=[c'a']$, $z=[ab]$, $z'=[a'b']$. Show that
$$[[xx'][yy'][zz']]=[abc][a'b'c'][[aa'][bb'][cc']]$$

Notes: This is from Gurevich, Foundations of the Theory of Algebraic Invariants, p. 138.

Why is the identity important?  If $a$, $b$, $c$, $a'$, $b'$, $c'$ are viewed as points in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ then $[[bc][b'c']]$ is the point of intersection of the lines $bc$, $b'c'$. So the LHS gives the condition that the points $bc\cap b'c'$, $ca\cap c'a'$, $ab\cap a'b'$ are collinear, while the third factor on RHS is the condition that the lines $aa'$, $bb'$, $cc'$ is concurrent. So this would give a proof of [Desargues' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem), and its converse.

Here are identities that are listed as helping in the proof:

$$[[ab]x]= (ax)b-(bx)a \\
[[ab][cd]] = [acd]b-[bcd]a = [abc]d-[abd]c$$

(another identity $([ab][cd]) = (ac)(bd)-(ad)(bc)$ might be useful here)

From the second identity we get
$$[[ab][cd][ef]]=[acd][bef]-[bcd][aef]=[abc][def]-[abd][cef]$$

This would allow us to tackle the LHS of the required identity, but I am a bit stuck at the moment.  Maybe both sides can be expressed in terms of mixed products, and then we can deduce all from the [Plucker relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding#Pl%C3%BCcker_relations).

Any ideas/hints would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity can be derived using a special case of Cauchy-Binet formula
$$
(p\times q)\cdot(u\times v)
=\det\begin{bmatrix} 
p\cdot u & p\cdot v\\ 
q\cdot u & q\cdot v\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or, in your symbols,
$$
[pq[uv]]=(pu)(qv)-(pv)(qu).\tag{0}
$$
Put $p=[xx'],\,q=[yy'],\,u=z$ and $q=z'$, we get
$$
\left[[xx'][yy'][zz']\right]
=[xx'z][yy'z']-[xx'z'][yy'z]\tag{1}
$$
Apply $(0)$ again, we further obtain
\begin{align}
[xx'z]
&=[xx'[ab]]
=(xa)(x'b)-(xb)(x'b)
=(xa)(x'b),\\
[yy'z']&=\cdots=(ya')(y'b'),\\
[xx'z']&=\cdots=-(xb')(x'a'),\\
[yy'z]&=\cdots=-(yb)(y'a).\\
\end{align}
Since $(xa)=(yb)=[abc]$ and $(y'b')=(x'a')=[a'b'c']$, the RHS of $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\left[[xx'][yy'][zz']\right]
=[abc][a'b'c']\left\{(x'b)(ya')-(xb')(y'a)\right\}.
$$
Now the result follows because
\begin{aligned}
&(x'b)(ya')-(xb')(y'a)\\
&=([b'c']b)([ca]a')-([bc]b')([c'a']a)\\
&=[b'c'b][caa']-[bcb'][c'a'a]\\
&=[bb'c'][aa'c]-[bb'c][aa'c']\quad\text{by permutations}\\
&=[[bb'][aa'][c'c]]\quad\text{by a parallel to } (1)\\
&=[[aa'][bb'][cc']].\\
\end{aligned}

Comment: Nice answer!  Now that I look at it, we only need to use the identity (1) and the fact that the triple product is skew-symmetric. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We'll use the equality for the triple product of cross products:

$$[[ab][cd][ef]]= [acd][bef]-[bcd][aef]$$

We get with the above
$$[[xx'][yy'][zz']]=[xyy'][x'zz']-[xzz'][x'yy']$$

Now substitute the values of $x$, $x'$, $\ldots$ in the triple products on the RHS. We get
$$[xyy']=[[bc][ca][c'a']]= [bca][cc'a']-[cca][bc'a']=[bca][cc'a']\\
[x'zz']=[[b'c'][ab][a'b']]=[b'ab][c'a'b']-[c'ab][b'a'b']=[b'ab][c'a'b']\\
[xzz']=[[bc][ab][a'b']]=[bab][ca'b']-[cab][ba'b']=-[cab][ba'b']\\
[x'yy']=[[b'c'][ca][c'a']]=[b'ca][c'c'a']-[c'ca][b'c'a']=-[c'ca][b'c'a']$$

Putting it all together we get
$$[[xx'][yy'][zz']]=[abc][a'b'c']([cc'a'][b'ab]- [ba'b'][c'ca])$$

Now, in the bracket on RHS we have (using the skew-symmetry of the triple product):
$$[abb'][a'cc']-[a'bb'][acc']=[[aa'][bb'][cc']]$$